# How should I use httpmethod PUT to send json to server in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, http, methods, put

I am a newbie in XCode4.3.

As mentioned in title, how should I use http method PUT to send a json data to my server?

My json is as follows:

```
{"password":"11111111","nickname":"yo", "email_address":"abc@abc.com"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need [NSURLRequest](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and then [NSURLConnection](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsurlconnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) objects. Your view controller can then implement the [NSURLConnectionDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSURLConnectionDelegate) protocol, and handle the response from the server. These links should get you going in the right direction.

The basic pattern is this:

1. Initialize a request with your body and method, etc
2. make a connection with it and set yourself as the delegate
3. handle the connection callbacks, building up an NSData of the response bytes
4. handle the connection's final callback `connectionDidFinishLoading:` to actually do something with your UI based on the response.